# Wrong cell insets in a UITableView added programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a tableViewController programmatically like so :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var tableView: UITableView!
    var elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map { "Elément \($0)" }


    // MARK: - View controller life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BasicTableViewCell")

        // Pin tableView to view
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let element = elements[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicTableViewCell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = element
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate { }
```

This is the storyboard, mostly empty:
[image: storyboard_empty]

This gives a strange cell inset on the leading and trailing side :

[image: iPad landscape_wrong]

---

What is really weird is: if I create an empty tableView in the storyboard (instead of adding it the the view programmatically), then everything is fine!

This is what the storyboard becomes, with an iBOutlet to the tableView.
[image: storyboard_tableView]

This is the class now (I didn't include the extensions, they are unchanged)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map { "Elément \($0)" }


    // MARK: - View controller life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BasicTableViewCell")
    }
}
```

The result:
[image: iPad_landscape_correct]

I can't believe there would be no way to create the tableView completely programmatically without this bug.
Did I miss a parameter on the tableView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth`. Just add it to your setup code.

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```

Comment: By the way, the problem arises because `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth` is `true` by default. So you (the OP) got caught by that. Apple now regrets this; in iOS 12, the default is `false` so this kind of thing won't happen.

Comment: Great! I didn’t know this property. Thanks!